# Buttons that clone themselves won't clone themselves anymore

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to clone a button when it is clicked and then allow the new button to have the same behavior? Would I need to use the onclick attribute instead of defining a jQuery click function? Here's my code:

```
    // Clone the current div, put it next door. (Currently appends to body)
    $('.split').on('click',function(){
        var newSwatchNum = Number($(this).attr('value'))+1;
        var thisSwatch = $(this).closest('div');
        var nextSwatch = thisSwatch.clone();

        // Set new values
        nextSwatch.attr('id', 'swatch-'+newSwatchNum);
        $(nextSwatch.children()[1]).attr('value', newSwatchNum);
        nextSwatch.appendTo('body');
    });
```

And the rest is in a JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/broinjc/2SbAD/

Comment: The best way to do this is probably to attach the click handler to a parent object and delegate. Something like `$('body').on('click','.buttonClass',function(){/*some code*/});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '.split', function() {
...
```

Event delegation can only occur if the element exists on load.

https://api.jquery.com/on/